# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed in ASP.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am continuously getting the following message while running my application.

```
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method     (HTTP verb) is being used.
```

I dont have any clue how this happening.

I tried to run this with undoing last changes but still its not working.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Could you show us your action that set by default when application starting? Is there any attributes?

Comment: This means that you specified an incorrect HTTP verb(Get, Post, Input) or incorrect input parameters. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it means that your Web Server is not recognizing the HTTP method(`GET,POST,DELETE,PUT` ...) in the request.

First, check in the RouteConfig.cs file which action run by defult.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In this case we have action Index from Home controller that was set by default.

Then, check that action. Is there any attributes like: `[HttpPost]`, `[HttpDelete]`, `[HttpPut]`, ...

If you use attribute then you maybe need to make small changes in ApplicationHost.config file to enable it:

1. Open in notepad the file: `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config`
2. In the ApplicationHost.config file, locate the `<handlers`> tag.
3. Make sure that all the handlers use valid HTTP methods.
4. Save the ApplicationHost.config file.